# Steps to determine the single element generators for a multiplicative group

Tags: group-theory

As student I've been asked the following question:

> Consider the specific prime $p=17$. Determine the single element generators (by hand or by Java program) of $F^*_{17}$. Recall $F^*_{17}$ is the multiplicative group of size $16 = 17−1$ formed by removing $0$ from the field $F^*_{17}$.

Can anyone explain what the steps are in order to attempt the question?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. For homework questions we provide hints. A generator $g$ of a group $G$, where the $F^*_{17}$ is a multiplicative cyclic group, is an element such that when you multiply $g$ itself, again and again, you will get all the elements of the group. Eventually, it will be 1. Now can you think methods? Also, see Little Fermat theorem,